# Qual a diferença entre text/javascript e text/x-javascript?

Tags: javascript

Content-Type: application/x-javascript
e
Content-Type: application/javascript

Comment: Pode ser uma pergunta interessante, seria melhor se voce pudesse detalhar melhor a duvida e talvez porque essa diferenca pode ser uma duvida/problema pra voce.

Comment: Uelsson, alguma das resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitar alguma delas agora? Seu feedback é muito importante para a comunidade.  Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 3):

- `text/javascript` é obsoleto
- `application/x-javascript` era experimental, e decidiram mudar oficialmente para o até então oficial `application/javascript`
- `application/javascript` é o *MIME Type* oficial para JavaScript

Os navegadores muitas vezes ignoram o "*tipo de conteúdo*" enviado pelo servidor e prestam muita atenção ao atributo `type` (e alguns ainda não reconhecem `application/javascript`, como no caso das versões anteriores ao IE 8).

Na maioria das situações, o *MIME Type* que o servidor envia não faz diferença prática. Entretanto a [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) recomenda escolher `application/javascript`:

> [...] *The media types*,
>
> ```
> * application/javascript
> * application/ecmascript
> ```
>
> *which are also defined in this document, are intended for common use
>     and should be used instead.*

Que em tradução livre seria:

> [...] *Os tipos de mídia*,
>
> ```
> * application/javascript
> * application/ecmascript
> ```
>
> *que também são definidos nesse documento são destinados a uso comum
>     e devem ser usados em vez disso.*

Também temos uma pergunta respondida sobre isso no nosso [Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876805).

Comment: Storm, vale lembrar apesar de não ser mais tão utilizado, que `application/javascript` não é compativel para versões do IE anteriores a 8.